# Problema a la hora de insertar datos en la BD

Tags: php, base-de-datos

tengo el siguiente problema. Hay un formulario que se debe llenar con los datos de un postgrado, pero si el postgrado es internacional, debo agregarle informaciones extras. El problema está a la hora de insertar un postgrado internacional que no lo hace. Comprobé cada uno x separado y si hacen la inserción a la BD a sus respectivas tablas. Pienso que el problema se encuentra en este fragmento de código. La manera que busque para saber cuando insertar el internacional fue mediente el valor que devuelve `$rbtnTipo`. Si conocen un método mejor se los agradecería o si saben donde puede estar el error, mucho mejor. Lo he estado analizando y no puedo reconocer donde esta dando problemas. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
<?php  

    include '../modelo/dao-postgrados.php';
    include '../modelo/dao-postgradoInt.php';
    extract($_REQUEST);

    if (isset($btn_postgrado)) {
        $post = new Postgrado($rbtnImpartido_Centro, $num_cant_alum, $num_cant_horas, $text_fecha_Inicio, $text_fecha_Final, text_codigo_postgrado, $rbtnTipo, $select_tema, $select_profesor);

        $post->InsertarPostgrado();
        $idPostgrado = $post->insert_id;

        //echo ("ID: ".$idPostgrado."Tipo: ". $rbtnTipo);
    }
    
    if ($rbtnTipo == 2){
        $postInt = new PostgradoInt($idPostgrado, $num_cant_alum_ext, $select_paises);
        $postInt->InsertarPostgradoInt();
    }

    header ("location: ../vista/pages/postgrados.php");

?>
```

La función de ejecutar consulta es de la clase **conexion()** y trabaja perfectamente.

```
function InsertarPostgrado(){
            $conexion = new Conexion();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO postgrado (impartidoCentro, cantAlumnos, cantHoras, fechaInicio, fechaFin, codigo, idTipoPostgrado, idTema, idProfesor) VALUES ('$this->impartidoCentro', '$this->cantAlumnos', '$this->cantHoras', '$this->fechaInicio', '$this->fechaFin', '$this->codigo', '$this->TipoPostgrado', '$this->Tema', '$this->Profesor')";
            
            $conexion->ejecutarConsulta($sql);
        }

function InsertarPostgradoInt(){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO postgradointernacional (idPostgrado, cantPaisesAlumnos, idImpartido) VALUES ('$this->idPostgrado', '$this->cantAlumnosInt', '$this->pais')";

            $conexion = new Conexion();
            $conexion->ejecutarConsulta($sql);
        }
```

Comment: Hola. Con ese código no podemos ver el problema. Depura los métodos implicados, mostrando lo que entra y sale mediante `var_dump`

Comment: ¿Que método necesitas k ponga en el artículo?```insertarPostgrado()``` e ```insertarPostgradoInt()```? ¿Cómo hago lo de ```var_dump```?